# How to run my script in selenium multiple times(Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I need your help,So the problem is that I wrote selenium scrip it's completly working.However,I want that my script run  multiple times again.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into a **function** and run it multiple times

```py
def main():
    #code

#for running function 10 times
for _ i range(10):
    main()

#for running function unlimited times
while True:
    main()
```